# I have Changed the Image Resource in android studio on button Clicked but it change once . i want it to change back the image if i clicked again

Tags: android

public void changeImage(View view){

```
    ImageView btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat1);


}
```

Comment: set btn.setbitmap(null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can react on click in Button OnClickListener for example.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Add here some logic for changing any images.
             }
         });
```

Or you can use selectors for that. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)